# simple apache2 reverse proxy setup not working

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I know what proxy is (very high level), it's just I have never set up one, and it feels like I might be missing some big fat point here.

My setup:

1. client
2. server (static IP), runs apache on port 80
3. proxy (has 2 network cards, one is on the clients network, the other one with a static IP on the server network), runs apache on port 80

I am trying to configure these three machines so that when client requests:

`http://proxy/machine1`

It gets served server's pages at server root URL, i.e.

`http://server/`

I can access client pages just fine. However, when I try accessing a page from the client machine, it simply gets redirected to server's IP address, which it clearly can't access since they are not on the same network:

...
       `<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://server/machine1"></meta>`
       `<title>Redirect</title>`
   ...

My apache2 config is:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /modules/mod_proxy_http.so


ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /machine1  http://server:80

<Location /machine1>
    ProxyPassReverse /
</Location>
```

What gives? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well it turns out that configuration was right, the problem with redirection happened because  http://server:80 redirected to http://server:80/ which was causing all the confusion :) Seems to work excellent now.