# Apache reverse proxy setup

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I have a jboss application server on machine1. The application address is `http://ip-address:8080/webapp`. I wanted to have only an ip pointing to the application. So on machine2 I setup an apache proxy. But it only helps to shift to port 80 but the directory `webapp` cannot be removed. So using proxy, the address is `http://ip-address/webapp`. So is there a way to just have the ip point to the application. For example the address `http://ip-address` should open the web page of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss integration with apache2 is best done using the Tomcat connector (mod_jk).

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingModjk12WithJBoss

Depending on your server environment you may even have readymade packages available to quickly setup mod_jk.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this SFq:

- [simple apache2 reverse proxy setup not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/195777/simple-apache2-reverse-proxy-setup-not-working)

Here's a bit more verbose version:

- http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

Take a look at "Debugging your Proxy Configuration" section.

Note that there may be issues with this setup, depending on what you app is doing. The simple case would be if you use any URLs in JavaScript - these may need to be converted if they change the behavior of the app in a way visible to the end user (e.g. doing redirects or so).

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_jk I have used Apache as front end to Tomcat.

The working vhost configuration I had is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName yourapp.name

ProxyPass / ajp://internal.com
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://internal.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Other security and logging directives you can include in the definition as per your needs/